# MongoDB Environment Variables Error, Unsure How to Proceed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, environment-variables

I am trying to learn full-stack web dev, and I am trying to set up MongoDB database to local ENV variables, but I am having problems. I do not know how to connect the `.env` file to my `server.js` file.

My `.env` file looks like this:

```
DATABASE_URL=mongodb://localhost/mybary
```

and `server.js` looks like this:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    require('dotenv').parse()
  }
  
  const express = require('express')
  const app = express()
  const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts')
  
  const indexRouter = require('./routes/index')
  
  app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views')
  app.set('layout', 'layouts/layout')
  app.use(expressLayouts)
  app.use(express.static('public'))
  
  const mongoose = require('mongoose')
  mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true })
  const db = mongoose.connection
  db.on('error', error => console.error(error))
  db.once('open', () => console.log('Connected to Mongoose'))
  
  app.use('/', indexRouter)
  
  app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000)
```

It throws this error:

```
src.toString().split(NEWLINES_MATCH).forEach(function (line, idx) {
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')
    at Object.parse (C:\Users\tangc\Desktop\site\node_modules\dotenv\lib\main.js:43:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\tangc\Desktop\site\server.js:4:23)
```

I believe the problem is in line two at `require('dotenv').parse()`, as I don't believe I am using that right, because when the server code looks like this it works (hard-coded the url):

```
const express = require('express')
  const app = express()
  const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts')
  
  const indexRouter = require('./routes/index')
  
  app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views')
  app.set('layout', 'layouts/layout')
  app.use(expressLayouts)
  app.use(express.static('public'))
  
  const mongoose = require('mongoose')
  mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mybary', { useNewUrlParser: true })
  const db = mongoose.connection
  db.on('error', error => console.error(error))
  db.once('open', () => console.log('Connected to Mongoose'))
  
  app.use('/', indexRouter)
  
  app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000)
```

I can't find a way to fix this on the web. If anything isn't clear, please comment.

Comment: Error is on `src.toString()` - your entire code does not contain any `src` value/variable. So, error *"Cannot read properties of undefined"* sounds logical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First - make sure that your `.env` file is in the root directory of your project.

Second - require `dotenv` as earliest as possible in your code `require("dotenv").config();`

Third - you shouldn't have any white spaces in your `.env` file. So `DATABASE_URL = mongodb://localhost/mybary` should be `DATABASE_URL=mongodb://localhost/mybary`

EDIT:
The `.parse()` is the engine that parses your `.env` file. I don't see why you would want to use it, unless you would like to override the `.env` file, just like it's mentioned in the docs.

Comment: I tried it... didn't change anything

Comment: I included the error in the question section, that might help

Comment: did you replace the `.parse()` to `.config()`?

Comment: That's what you meant!  Thank you, it fixed it!

Comment: Sorry, now it gives an `MongooseError: The 'uri' parameter to 'openUri()' must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to 'mongoose.connect()' or 'mongoose.createConnection()' is a string.
string.` error

Comment: is your `.env` file in the root directory of your project? follow the steps in my answer it really shouldn't be this complicated. keep us updated

Comment: I closed and opened vscode again and it worked. IDK why. Thank you, though!

Answer (score 0):

If you use node to run server.js, you can run it like this

```sh
node -r dotenv/config server.js
```

or

```sh
export DATABASE_URL = mongodb://localhost/mybary
node server.js
```

FYI: Export the values on the server, it should be easy to manage different environments. For example, different servers have different ip and database hosts. When I install it, I don’t need to set any configuration, just overwrite.

Comment: not sure where to put the export statement...

Comment: I included the error in the question section, that might help

Comment: export in the command line